# How to set variable in batchfile

Tags: batch-file

I want to move files according to folder names.

1.Some folder names have been written in b2.txt. In my b2.txt, every line contains one or two or three words, connected by space or "-". Like this:

```
transfer print
anti-foamer
insect
fibre reinforced plastic
```

2.My files are in "E:\JP-XIN\".

3.In E disk, there must exist one (only one) folder name consisting of one line in b2.txt.

My question is how to set every line in b2.txt exactly as variable.

In the following code, "%%k" is the file name gotten by searching, "%%l" is the path to the folder gotten by searching. The code did not work correctly.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%a in (b2.txt) do (
    set VAR=%%a
    for /f "delims=" %%k in ('dir /s/b/a-d E:\JP-XIN\*.pdf E:\JP-XIN\*.txt  ^| findstr /i /c:"!VAR!"') do (
        for /f "delims=" %%l in ('dir /s/b/a:d-h E:\ ^| findstr /i /c:"!VAR!"') do (
            if not "%%l"=="" move "%%k" "%%~fsl"
)))
pause
```

Comment: Excuse me. I don't understand what you want. I think would be easier if you show us what the value of what variable you want to be given the b2.txt file as input. You may use a cascade of partial results (given this data I want these results, and given that results I want these second results, etc.)

Comment: Thanks!I want to get "!VAR!" equalled to original line in b2.txt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [move files according to folder names (batch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031862/move-files-according-to-folder-names-batch)

Comment: @leescott: You already done that with `for /f "delims=" %%a in (b2.txt) do (`  `set VAR=%%a`, so?

Comment: That echoed a wrong result!Such as,b2.txt contains "water-proof",E disk contains folder "waterproof,water-proof,corrosion proof",but, file containing "water-proof or waterproof" were moved into "corrosion proof".

Comment: @leescott: Excuse me. 1-I don't understand what your code try to achieve. Your explanation is confusing and the code is tricky. 2-In your example the b2.file does NOT contain "water-proof". 3-I don't know what E disk contains. 4-Do you want I debug a code I don't understand? or you want I help you to find some errors? or, better yet, you want I help you to achieve a process that I must understand first. Try to explain it in simpler terms. 5-Read again my first comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some time to spent so I worked overtime in how to solve what I think your problem is.

If your requirements are these:

1. The b2.txt file contains several folder names, with possible spaces.
2. In E:\ there is one folder that is contained in b2.txt.
3. In E:\JP-XIN\ there are several *.pdf and *.txt files.

and you want to:

1. Locate the folder that is contained in b2.txt, and
2. Move to it the *.pdf and *.txt files that have the same name of the folder

then the Batch file below solve your problem:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (b2.txt) do (
    if exist "E:\%%a" (
        move "E:\JP-XIN\%%a.pdf" "E:\%%a"
        move "E:\JP-XIN\%%a.txt" "E:\%%a"
    )
)
```

If the .pdf and .txt are the only files with that name, then the two `move` commands may be joined in just one:

```
        move "E:\JP-XIN\%%a.*" "E:\%%a"
```

If this is not your problem then, please, tell us what your problem is!

Comment: Thanks for your hearty assistance!I think the code is more concise and brief than mine.I guess  the last five "%%a" changed into " * %%a * " maybe better for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `tokens=*` to return the entire line as a single variable.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (b2.txt) do (
```

---

You can also write things like `tokens=1,2*` which makes the first variable token 1, the second variable token 2, and the third variable the rest of the line.  So the text:

```
Several words on a line.
```

Would split to:

```
%%a = Several
%%b = words
%%c = on a line.
```

Comment: Thanks! I  try this means,but it doesn't make effect for my code.I don't know why.Space!Space!!

Comment: it turns out your original code sets the `%%a` variable correctly.  I think you have issues elsewhere inside the `for` loop.  Get rid of the `@echo off` line so you can see what the loop is actually doing and debug your script.

Comment: I know that means,but I never do it.Your reminder opens a new windows for me to study batchfile.Thanks!

Comment: I find my code have some wrong and my txt designed imperfectly.Finally ,I get answer.Thanks all to help me!Best wishes!